# Asking: interpret tobit regression to estimate willingness to pay from payment card

Tags: probability, econometrics, interpretation, tobit-regression

I have a research question, that I have to evaluate the Willingness to pay data for conservation. My input data in the type of payment card : $0, <\$2, \$2-\$4, \dotsc, >\$10$. I use middle point of each interval to get the data $0,\$1,\$3, \dotsc $ then I try to use tobit model, corner solution  to elicit the data. But currently I could not interpret the equation. Could you give me some suggestion?

[image]

Comment: This question does not seem answerable to me as is. You don't provide any guidance on how your payment card covariate relates to the RHS variables in the regression table.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov thank you for responding me Q28_tobit is WTP data which I collected from payment card 0, <$2, $2-$4, $4-$6, $6-$8, $8-$10 and >$10. Q21- previous experience binary yes/no 1/0. Q23 and Q24 perception on using wild animals as food and keeping wild animal in captivity  respectively-strongly disagree-strongly agree (1-5). Q6- income, logQ6 - log income. o collect data of WTP respondents could opt one among those payment cards.   Thank you again

Comment: The table you've reproduced contains roughly 75 results.  Could you narrow down what it is you would like to know?

Comment: I would like to know how to evaluate the R square of this tobit model? how could i get this data. Then finally, i would like to evaluate the E(WTP when WTP>0). If it capable?

Comment: By the way I have just run the data again. I get that i need to compare between OLS and tobit to get the data of Average Partial Effect (APE)  and Partial Average Effect (PEA) to calculate R squared and σˆ of tobit. I am reading books - introductory Econometric but to be honest, i am not really understand how those data were calculated.  It is capable if you explain me how to compute?  Such a shame! I am studying on my own and i do not understand. I even couldnoy understand the explaination in example 17.2 page 540 of Wooldridge book. Could someone help me to understand it please?